# ggplot2: Change the order of `color`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a figure like below and I would like to change the order of colored lines from blue->green->red to r->g->b, so that it is the same as the legend's order. I have found several tutorials to change the order of legends, but I want to keep its order in this case (since they are 1, 2, and 3).

[image: Figure]

Here is the code to generate the data and figure.

```
population_num <- 100
population <- tibble(
    gender = as.numeric(rbinom(population_num, 1, 0.5)),
    age=rnorm(population_num, mean=50, sd=20),
    score=rnorm(population_num, mean=80, sd=30),
    setid=sample(c(1,2,3), size=population_num, replace=T)
    )
temp <- population %>%
  group_by(setid) %>%
  do(model1 = tidy(lm(score ~ age, data = .)),
     model2 = tidy(lm(score ~ age + gender, data = .))) %>% 
  gather(model_name, model, -setid) %>%                     
  unnest() %>%                                              
  filter(term == "age")                                     

interval1 <- -qnorm((1-0.9)/2)

ggplot(temp, aes(colour = as.factor(setid))) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = gray(1/2), lty = 2) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x = model_name, ymin = estimate - std.error*interval1,
                     ymax = estimate + std.error*interval1),
                 lwd = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 1/2)) +
 scale_x_discrete(limits=c("model2", "model1"), labels=c("M2", "M1")) +
  coord_flip()
```

(This question is once asked in Japanese Stackoverflow, but couldn't get answers.)

Comment: Which package is the `tidy` function from? I'm sure I already seen that, but `tidyverse` gives no result

Comment: @GGamba, it should be `broom`.

Comment: Just change `position` to `position_dodge(width = -1/2)`

Comment: @alistaire Thanks. Then, is it possible to change it to the arbitrary order? Some blogs say ggplot2 uses the order in the dataset (for example, if `setid=2` rows are above of the `setid=1`, `2` comes first). But it seems your answer implies we can only make it reverse.

Comment: ggplot sets element order by factor levels, so if you specify (e.g. `factor(setid, levels = c(2,1,3))`, you can rearrange. If you just want to change colors, you can use whichever `scale_colour_*` function you prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `width` parameter of `position_dodge` to a negative. This does produce a warning:

> ```
> Warning message:
> position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals
> ```

but plots fine:

```r
ggplot(temp, aes(colour = as.factor(setid))) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = gray(1/2), lty = 2) +
    geom_linerange(aes(x = model_name, ymin = estimate - std.error*interval1,
                       ymax = estimate + std.error*interval1),
                   lwd = 1, position = position_dodge(width = -1/2)) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits=c("model2", "model1"), labels=c("M2", "M1")) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]